# cUrl keep on sending header information if set to false

Tags: php, curl, header, http-headers, zend-framework2

With cUrl I want to get a xml file to read it after with SimpleXmlElement. But because cUrl keep on sending header information at the response my XML document is invalid.

What do I have to do to leave the HTTP header information?

Part of the data I get returned:

```
string(8056) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\nContent-Type: text/xml\r\nDate: Wed, 19 Dec 2012 11:15:45 GMT\r\n\r\n
    <?xml version="1.0"?>\n
```

My code (ZF2)

```
$request = new Request();
        $request->setUri($url);

        $adapter = new Curl();
        $client  = new Client();
        $client->setAdapter($adapter);

        $adapter->setOptions(array(
            'curloptions' => array(
                CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 4,
            )
        ));

        $response = $client->dispatch($request);
```

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Comment: What library are you using? new Curl() is not plain PHP...

Comment: I make use of 
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Client;
use Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl;

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP manual, CURLOPT_HEADER should be set to true or false.

**To remove the header output, simply add this code:**

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => false
```

I don't know what cURL class you're using, because there's no such class built-in PHP.

**Full code:**

```
$request = new Request();
$request->setUri($url);

$adapter = new Curl();
$client  = new Client();
$client->setAdapter($adapter);

$adapter->setOptions(array(
    'curloptions' => array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 4
    )
));

$response = $client->dispatch($request);
```

Does this work for you? Else I'll give you an updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to use '$response->getBody();' ! This did the trick.

$request = new Request();
        $request->setUri($url);

```
    $adapter = new Curl();
    $client  = new Client();
    $client->setAdapter($adapter);

    $adapter->setOptions(array(
        'curloptions' => array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 4,
        )
    ));

    $response = $client->send($request);
    $data = $response->getBody();

    return $data;
```